# Keep TopLevel window in front of main window

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller

I created a TopLevel window that appears in front of my main window when it pops up. It works as intended when I run the program from the command line. The problem occurs when I turn the program into an executable using pyinstaller. Then when the TopLevel window pops up it appears in front of the main window for a brief moment and then moves behind it. To get around this, I'm using `toplevel.attributes('-topmost',True)`, but this makes the window stay on top of ALL windows and can't be moved behind them. Why would pyinstaller cause this to happen, and what can I do to get it back to how it worked previously?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a modal window? You need to use the command `Toplevel.transient(master)`. [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/ac4816791a0a7f15497bb8f17cb32612).

Answer (score 0):

Try top-level.grab_set() with this it will appear on top of the main window and you have to close it before you can work on the window

Comment: [No, grab_set has to do with event handleing](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.grab_set-method). You are thinking of [transient](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.transient-method).

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure it always comes to the top

```
a = TopLevel()
a.lift()
a.attributes('-topmost',True)
a.after_idle(a.attributes,'-topmost',False)
```

You can also hide your root with

```
root.withdraw()
```

Then bring it back with

```
root.deiconfy()
```